# my eclipse install another app instead of mine in emulator

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with my eclipse i have edited my app and it's ready with no error shows but now when i run it into my emulator it runs another app i have in my eclipse so i deleted the app and still i run the application i want in the eclipse and still it shows the old app that i didn't even ask to install it in my emulator so it's installing an app that i don't have at first place in my eclipse i don't know how it is possible i cleaned my project and still the problem is there and changed my emulator still its install the old app for me

Answer (score 2):

uninstall the app from the emulator and check in your run configuration about the running app and try with new emulator

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have selected in package explorer the app you want to run. Try to unistall the app from the emulator or create a new device on emulator. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the Run configuration: Run->Run configuration. Under the Android tab, choose your project. If you run in Debug, you have similar option too.
2. Another similar case I saw, is that some application was installed, but the name was not updated. Verify the names of your application in both the strings.xml and the Manifest. (If you create a project by duplicating another one, it might be the problem).